# Importing tab delim data into R

Tags: r, readr, csv

I'm trying to set up a reproducible workflow for reading and formatting lots of messy tab separated txt datatables, but am struggling to find a function that will correctly read in the data.

The first row has a single value, and then subsequent rows have varying numbers of blank cells and then values. {unpivitR} will handle it once I've read the data in, but I can't for the life of me get it to parse more than the first col - there should be up to 150 or more but all the blanks in the first row are causing an issue, and I unfortunately can't drop the first row. If I manually (in excel...) convert it from a txt to csv file, it imports perfectly, but that's ideally not the route I'd like to take. I generally default to {readr} functions for importing, but definitely open to other suggestions!

For example:

```
read_tsv("Name\n
         \t\t\tdet_1\tdet_2\n
         \t\t\t4\t5\n
         10:10\tSS\tXY\t6\t7", col_names = FALSE)
```

imports as:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  X1   
  <chr>
1 Name 
2 NA   
3 NA   
4 10:10
```

With the warning:

> Warning: 3 parsing failures. 
> row col  expected    actual         file
> 2  -- 1 columns 5 columns literal data
> 3  -- 1 columns 5 columns literal data
> 4  -- 1 columns 5 columns literal data

Where ideally it would read like:
`read_tsv("Name\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tdet_1\tdet_2\n\t\t\t4\t5\n10:10\tSS\tXY\t6\t7", col_names = FALSE)`

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Name  NA    NA    NA    NA   
2 NA    NA    NA    det_1 det_2
3 NA    NA    NA    4     5    
4 10:10 SS    XY    6     7
```

Any pointers or do I just have to take a hit and manually convert it to csvs. I've got to map the function through a whole list of files, with slightly different set ups, so I can't write something specific for each file.

Updated:
I've just realised my reprex was too simple to fully replicate the problem. The data get randomly wider, up to ca. 200 cols about 200 rows down (though not consistently...). In this example the "12" should be on row 10.

```
read.delim(text = "Name\n
         \t\tdet_1\t\n
         \t\t\t4\n
         \t\t\t5\n
         \t\t\t6\n
         \t\t\t7\n
         \t\t\t8\n
         \t\t\t9\n
         \t\t\t10\n
         10:10\tSS\tXY\t11\t12", sep = "\t", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, na.strings = "", strip.white = TRUE)
```

which returns:

```
      V1   V2    V3 V4
1   Name <NA>  <NA> NA
2   <NA> <NA> det_1 NA
3   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  4
4   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  5
5   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  6
6   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  7
7   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  8
8   <NA> <NA>  <NA>  9
9   <NA> <NA>  <NA> 10
10 10:10   SS    XY 11
11    12 <NA>  <NA> NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `read.csv` from `base R` with `fill = TRUE`

```
read.csv(text = "Name\n
         \t\t\tdet_1\tdet_2\n
         \t\t\t4\t5\n
         10:10\tSS\tXY\t6\t7", sep="\t", 
              header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, na.strings = "",strip.white = TRUE)
```

-output

```
    V1   V2   V3    V4    V5
1  Name <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA> <NA> <NA> det_1 det_2
3  <NA> <NA> <NA>     4     5
4 10:10   SS   XY     6     7
```

Comment: or `read.delim` , which even has `fill=TRUE` as default ... but would need `header=FALSE`

Comment: Thanks both! This sort of works, but it doesn't capture the full width of the data. Sorry, my reprex wasn't up to scratch, so I've updated the question with a new example.